# How to associate through a join table that reference the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called `House` and I want to be able to associate houses with each other to show recommendations.

So I would expect that given a house, I should be able to ask: `house.recommended_houses`. A house could be recommended for more than one house.

I was thinking on having a table that would store this association (I don't know the name yet), so it would have the following columns:

```
recommended_house_id
recommended_for_house_id
```

I am failing to understand how would I hook this up with my `House` model. What would the associations look like, and also what name should I be using for that join model?

Comment: What type of association do you need: `one-to-many` or `many-to-many`?

Comment: Many to Many. A product has many recommendations, and a product can be recommended by many other products.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recommendations,
      class_name: "House",
      foreign_key: "recommended_by_id",
      association_foreign_key: "recommendation_id"
end
```

Comment: Then how do you distinct given a house if you want to find all the recommended houses, or all the houses it has been recommended by?

Comment: The easy way of thinking about it is to imagine that it is not a self-join table, but two different models. For example, categories and products. Category can have many products, product can be in many categories. How would you distinct in this case? It's same here...

Comment: Right, but how would you write the associations so that I can do `house.recommended_houses` and `house.recommended_by_houses`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is called a self-referential association.

You can set up a join table (recommendations) and the associated model:

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :recommended_house, :class_name => 'House'

end
```

and then use has_many, :through relationships within the House model to set up the relationships you're looking for.

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :recommendations
  has_many :recommended_houses, :through => :recommendations

  has_many :inverse_recommendations, :class_name => "Recommendation", :foreign_key => "recommended_house_id"
  has_many :recommended_by_houses, :through => :inverse_recommendations, :source => :house

end
```

Now you can use both `house.recommended_houses` and `house.recommended_by_houses`.